# BigCommerce Simply pull customer address using jquery?

Tags: jquery, bigcommerce

I just want to pull a customer's address using jquery. Is this possible? Can anyone post an example script? Thanks... what a nebulous construct BC is...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when you're trying to gather customer information. But if it's around time of login, you could look at using the login mutation with GraphQL. This now returns the full customer object. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog#publications/graphql-login-mutation-now-returns-entire-customer-object

Answer (score 0):

> Hey, You can get Customer Addresses from a BigCommerce store with the code below:

```
         var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "URL": 
     "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/<storehash>/v3/customers/addresses",
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
               "accept": "application/json",
               "content-type": "application/json",
               "x-auth-token": "<token>"
            },
            "processData": false
          }
    
         $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response); // here you will see the response.
         });
```

> OR

```
         fetch(`https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/<storehash>/v3/customers/addresses`,{
            method: 'GET',  
            headers: {
              'X-Auth-Token': '<token>',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': `application/json`
            }
         })  
         .then((res) => res.json())  
         .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

> Take care that your BigCommerce Token should have Read Customer access during API Creation Process i.e.
> API Creation Process: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Store-API-Accounts?language=en_US#creating